# LibGit2Sharp-ssh. Unable to load shared library 'git2-ssh-baa87df'

Tags: libgit2sharp-ssh

I'm using LibGit2Sharp-ssh library for clone repository.

```
string repositoryUrl = "ssh://git@git.somehost.net/project-name/repo-name.git";
LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(repositoryUrl, localPath, new LibGit2Sharp.CloneOptions { CredentialsProvider = MyCredentialsProvider });

private Credentials MyCredentialsProvider(string url, string usernameFromUrl, SupportedCredentialTypes types)
    {
        var sshDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        return new LibGit2Sharp.SshUserKeyCredentials()
        {
            Username = usernameFromUrl,
            Passphrase = string.Empty,
            PublicKey = Path.Combine(sshDir, "id_rsa.pub"),
            PrivateKey = Path.Combine(sshDir, "private_key.pem"),
        };
    }
```

But getting error
*Unable to load shared library 'git2-ssh-baa87df' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libgit2-ssh-baa87df, 0x0001): tried: 'libgit2-ssh-baa87df' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibgit2-ssh-baa87df' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgit2-ssh-baa87df' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libgit2-ssh-baa87df' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgit2-ssh-baa87df' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgit2-ssh-baa87df' (no such file, not in dyld cache)*

How to fix it?

**My OS is mac and i'm using .net 6**. I already tryed to copy libgit2-ssh-baa87df library to debug and /usr/local/lib folders. But it doesn't help.